# How to show jsp page in lightbox onSelectRowTopics of struts jquery grid?

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

Here is the brief code please share your idea,i am using struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.2.1

```
   <s:url id="remoteurl"  action="CustomExtaction" namespace="/forcustomtemplete"/>                                                 
                                <sjg:grid
                                    id="gridtable"
                                    caption="Exercises "
                                    dataType="json"
                                    href="%{remoteurl}"
                                    gridModel="gridModel"
                                    cssClass="ui.jqgrid"
                                    height="345"
                                    width="1285"
                                    onSelectRowTopics="rowselected"
                                    loadonce="true"
                                    >
                                    <sjg:gridColumn name="exidd" cssClass="ui.jqgrid"  index="exId" title="Exercise Name" sortable="true" key="true" />
                                    <sjg:gridColumn name="sets" cssClass="ui.jqgrid" index="sets" title="Sets" sortable="true" key="true" />
                                    <sjg:gridColumn name="reps" cssClass="ui.jqgrid" index="reps" title="Reps" sortable="true" key="true"/>
                                    <sjg:gridColumn name="imgpath" cssClass="ui.jqgrid" align="center" index="imgpath"  title="Image" key="true" sortable="true"  formatter="formatLink"  />
                                </sjg:grid>
```

Comment: how to do this? Please share to me.

Comment: thank you to tell me this, onward i will do that.

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi can you help me on this question?

Comment: i am afraid i can help you here and i never used Jquery plugin and has always relied on plain Jquery.

Comment: @Quincy onSelectRowTopics i am calling jQuery lightbox and an Action ,then in struts.xml returning one .jsp page. i want to show this jsp page in lightbox.but my light box is not coming, i think my jqury library is conflicting.